# QGIS view bounding box on Add vector layer GeoGSON protocol?

Tags: qgis, geojson, ogr

Our server can serve GeoJSON with an optional bounding box HTTP parameter. e.g. `http://our_gis_server.org.au/layername?bbox=xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax`

In QGIS I can add this vector layer as a Protocol and point directly at the server. Is it possible to pass the current view bounding box dynamically as part of this query to reduce load on the server? I.E. can QGIS pass in the map bounding box as parameters to the protocol call?